# kivy - getting a spinner to remember its selection

Tags: python-3.x, spinner, kivy, jsonstore, getselection

I was hoping someone could tell me the way you can get a spinner to remember its value when an app is loaded.

I was thinking about using from kivy.storage.jsonstore import JsonStore to store and retrieve the value the user selects in a db, this is easy enough.

But having searched for hours I can't find any documentation on making the spinner say that value when it loads.

for example I have a lot of items in my spinner (about 60) and it takes a while to scroll through, as I said I can remember the last selected item but I cannot work out how to make it the default value.

```
    Spinner:
    id: stationSpinner
    text:'Select a Station'
    values: ('Reset Saved Station','Appledore','Axminster','Bampton','Barnstaple','Bere Alston','Bideford','Bovey Tracey','Braunton','Bridgwater','Brixham','Buckfastleigh','Budleigh Salterton','Burnham on Sea','Camels Head','Castle Cary','Chagford','Chard','Cheddar','Chulmleigh','Colyton','Combe Martin','Crediton','Crewkerne','Crownhill','Cullompton','Dartmouth','Dawlish','Danes Castle','Middlemoor','Exmouth','Frome','Glastonbury','Greenbank','Hartland','Hatherleigh','Holsworthy','Honiton','Ilfracombe','Ilminster','Ivybridge','Kingsbridge','Kingston','Lundy Island','Lynton','Martock','Minehead','Modbury','Moretonhampstead','Nether Stowey','Newton Abbot','North Tawton','Okehampton','Ottery St Mary','Paignton','Plympton','Plymstock','Porlock','Princetown','Salcombe','Seaton','Shepton Mallet','Sidmouth','Somerton','South Molton','Street','Taunton','Tavistock','Teignmouth','Tiverton','Topsham','Torquay','Torrington','Totnes','USAR','Wellington','Wells','Williton','Wincanton','Witheridge','Wiveliscombe','Woolacombe','Yelverton','Yeovil')
    size_hint: None, None
    size: (150, 44)
    pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'y': 0.35}
    on_text: app.show_selected_value()
```

so the first time the app is loaded it says  'select a station'. The second time its loaded it shows the last selected station. Obviously I have put the reset option in to clear the db file.

I have tried just using

```
SvdStn = store.get('Stations')['Saved']
self.root.station.text = SvdStn
```

but it doesnt work, I'm guessing its fairly simple but as I can't find any documentation on it I can't get my head around it... I'll keep looking and maybe come at it from a different direction, maybe have a button become visible with the last one selected next to the spinner, but if the db is empty set the visible property to false.

edit: here is my code [py file and logo on onedrive](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=2251DB42584BA5BE%213408)

Any ideas welcome

Thanks

Raif

This is the relevant part of code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.storage.jsonstore import JsonStore
from os.path import join

kv = '''
<IncidentScreen>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    station: stationSpinner
    Image:
        source:'DSFRSLogo.png'
        allow_stretch:True
        pos_hint: {'root.x':0.5, 'y':.2}

    Spinner:
        id: stationSpinner
        text:'Select a Station'
        values: ('Reset Saved Station','Appledore','Axminster','Bampton','Barnstaple','Bere Alston','Bideford','Bovey Tracey','Braunton','Bridgwater','Brixham','Buckfastleigh','Budleigh Salterton','Burnham on Sea','Camels Head','Castle Cary','Chagford','Chard','Cheddar','Chulmleigh','Colyton','Combe Martin','Crediton','Crewkerne','Crownhill','Cullompton','Dartmouth','Dawlish','Danes Castle','Middlemoor','Exmouth','Frome','Glastonbury','Greenbank','Hartland','Hatherleigh','Holsworthy','Honiton','Ilfracombe','Ilminster','Ivybridge','Kingsbridge','Kingston','Lundy Island','Lynton','Martock','Minehead','Modbury','Moretonhampstead','Nether Stowey','Newton Abbot','North Tawton','Okehampton','Ottery St Mary','Paignton','Plympton','Plymstock','Porlock','Princetown','Salcombe','Seaton','Shepton Mallet','Sidmouth','Somerton','South Molton','Street','Taunton','Tavistock','Teignmouth','Tiverton','Topsham','Torquay','Torrington','Totnes','USAR','Wellington','Wells','Williton','Wincanton','Witheridge','Wiveliscombe','Woolacombe','Yelverton','Yeovil')
        size_hint: None, None
        size: (150, 44)
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'y': 0.35}
        on_text: app.show_selected_value()

'''
class IncidentScreen(FloatLayout):
    station = ObjectProperty(None)
    results = ObjectProperty(None)
    data_dir = App().user_data_dir
    store = JsonStore(join(data_dir, 'storage.json'))
    try:
        store.get('stations')['saved']
    except KeyError:
        SvdStn = ""
    else:
        SvdStn = store.get('stations')['saved']
        print(SvdStn)
        self.root.station.text = SvdStn

class DSFRSapp(App):

    def build(self):            
        Builder.load_string(kv)
        fl = IncidentScreen()
        return fl

if __name__ =="__main__":
    DSFRSapp().run()
```

Comment: Just setting its text as you have tried should work. Can you post a minimal working example demonstrating the full code?

Comment: minimal working example?... no ha ha because I have no idea what that is.... is there a way i could upload the py file?

Comment: class IncidentScreen(FloatLayout):
    station = ObjectProperty(None)
    results = ObjectProperty(None)
    data_dir = App().user_data_dir
    store = JsonStore(join(data_dir, 'storage.json'))
    try:
        store.get('stations')['saved']
    except KeyError:
        SvdStn = ""
    else:
        SvdStn = store.get('stations')['saved']
        self.root.station.text = SvdStn
    
class DSFRSapp(App):
    
    def build(self):            
        Builder.load_string(kv)
        fl = IncidentScreen()
        return fl

Comment: ummm that looks messy! i really would like to upload the file or i could email it? @inclement

Comment: A minimal working example means an example that is minimal (doesn't include unnecessary code to demonstrate the problem) and working (the code can be run and demonstrates the problem). If you want to show the .py file, edit it into your original post.

Comment: @inclement I have uploaded it to my one drive and have given you a link to in in the post. thanks

Comment: It would be preferable to paste the code into your post.

Answer (score 0):

The method that you've mentioned for spinner works fine but It looks like you've misunderstood the use of `self` and `App()`. `self` refers to the current instance of a class and is supplied as an argument to a class method so you can't use it outside of a class method. You've tried to use it directly under the kivy properties but in that case it doesn't contain a value. You also attempt to use `App()` but this attempts to creates an instance of the App object. I would leave the loading and saving in the application class and allow the spinner to be initialised with an extra argument to it's constructor, like so:

```
class IncidentScreen(FloatLayout):
    station = ObjectProperty(None)
    results = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, station, **kwargs):
        super(IncidentScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.station.text = station

class DSFRSapp(App):

    def build(self):            
        Builder.load_string(kv)
        data_dir = self.user_data_dir
        store = JsonStore(join(data_dir, 'storage.json'))
        SvdStn = ""

        try:
            store.get('stations')['saved']
            SvdStn = store.get('stations')['saved']
        except KeyError:
            pass

        fl = IncidentScreen(SvdStn)
        return fl
```

You'll have to do something similar for the `show_selected_value` method. I had to disable it to get the code running because it's called immediately as the gui displays. Overall, I'd recommend that you take a careful look at how python handles classes. It'll save you a lot of effort later on. There are lots of tutorials if you google around.

Comment: Thanks i will look into the tutorials like yo said, im going through the Codeacedemy course, I will mar t e question when i understand enough to say if its helped or not. Thanks again!